# Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'name_t' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

This is the structure i declared

Just right after entered the student number and the moment i hit enter key and it give me the error "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'name_t' is being used without being initialized."

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    int number;
    char name, transaction;
    struct node *next;

}*newNode, *list, *temp;

void insertNode();
void displayNode();
void deleteNode();
```

Below is the insert function i wrote

```
void insertNode()
{
    int number_t;
    char name_t, transaction_t;

    newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    printf("Enter Student number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_t);

    newNode->number = number_t;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    printf("Enter Student name: ");
    scanf("%s", name_t);

    newNode->name = name_t;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    printf("Enter Transcation Desciption: ");
    scanf("%s", transaction_t);

    newNode->transaction = transaction_t;
    newNode->next = NULL;


    if (list == NULL)
        list = newNode;
    else
    {
        temp = list;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `name_t` is a single character. It can't hold a string. In this case its (*indeterminate*) value is converted into a pointer which is used by `scanf` as the destination for the string, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And unrelated to your problem, your naming of the variables is, well, *unusual*. :) Usually the `_t` suffix is used for *types*, like `time_t` or `size_t` or `uint32_t`.

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions, do not cast the result, that just clutters the code.  The returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer   NOTE:  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` format specifier, always include a 'max characters' modifier (that is one less than the length of the input buffer) to assure that the user will not overrun the input buffer (which would result in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: in the posted code, the fields: `name_t` and `transaction_t` are only one byte and the `%s` always appends a NUL byte tot he input, AND the parameters to the call to `scanf()` will treat the (ininitialized) contents of thsoe fields as address values, This results in undefined behavour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: to avoid some massive headaches while debugging, when writing a comparison with `==`, always place the literal on the left, so the compiler will catch any error, like using `=` rather than `==`

Comment: Thanks guys ! I had solve it using strcpy, but still thanks a lot for all the advise and methods! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", name_t);
```

`scanf` is expecting a string, but you are passing a plain `char` (with not enough room to store a string)

I suggest `fgets` in order to avoid buffer overflows:

```
char name[100]; /* name_t is not a good name for a variable */
char *ptr;

if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin)) {
    /* strip the trailing newline */
    ptr = strchr(name, '\n');
    if (ptr != NULL) {
        *ptr = '\0';
    }
}
```